# Each Product only 1 in shopping basket

Tags: product, shopping

i am selling events with magento. is it possible to add every product only one time to the shopping basket? When it is already added to the basket, then you can´t add it another time?

Comment: are want add product qty 1 or add only add product one time

Answer (score 2):

Andre Sancken,

Magento  have `an attribute which is set maximum no of product qty`  for cart.If s`et it to  1 then any customer cannot   qty 1 of products`

Maximum Quantity Allowed `in Shopping Cart - with this option you can control the maximum number of items that customers can add to the shopping cart`. By `default,` it's `set to 10000.` Note that this `will affect not the whole cart but each line in the cart`. This means that a customer can order the maximum allowed quantity from a certain product, and they `can then put units from another product in the same cart/order, so that the actual total items of both products exceeds the allowed quantity`. As with the previous two settings this one will affect not only those products that you add after you make a change to this setting but the change will also affect existing products. If `you want to, you can set a different value for this setting per product from the settings of each particular product`.

**How to managed:**

It managed globally  ,goto  Magento and go to **System menu>Configuration>Inventory** button in the Catalog section on the left >
then goto it `Product Stock Option> find  Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart: make it 1`
That makes customer  cannot cart more then one qty .This **effecting on all the products**

**[EDIT:Product wise]**
Also ,you can  `do it product wish` goto `admin>Catalog>Managed Product>Select a Product` Then go to  `it inventory tab` here you find same field which managed this product wise max qty cart

Thx but this is not what i need. With this, it also possible to put the product another time to the cart. I want the following: Every User can put every product from my Shop but only qty1 every product 1 time. With your explanations i can put only one product to the cart

Comment: This makes my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 1):

Each of it. When you add the product, it should not be possible to add it another time and also only 1 qty per product.

Comment: donot put comment as answer>just edit question or put comment